# How can I determine which element in a matrix is closest to a given point using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix *data* of (x,y) coordinates which looks like this:

```
array([[3,4], [10,4], [1,3], [5,8]])
```

I want to write a piece of code that, given a numpy array with generic coordinates (x,y), finds the index of the row of the matrix which corresponds to the closest point to (x,y) (in terms of euclidean distance).

So far what I have done is :

```
point = np.asarray([x, y])
closest_pt_idx = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(data, point), axis=1))
```

Which for some reason doesnt seem to work well. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This looks kinda correct (minor syntax error in `asarray`). What errors do you get?

Comment: `point = np.asarray((x, y))`

Comment: Yes thanks you are right, i missed a parenthesis, but i didnt in the actual code

Comment: It seems to work fine for some points but for others it gives very wrong results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a single-liner for this.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[3,4],[10,4],[1,3],[5,8],[2,3]])
point = np.tile([2,3], (len(data),1))
closest_pt_idx = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(data-point,axis=1))
print(np.linalg.norm(data-point,axis=1),closest_pt_idx)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have solved it. Still not sure why my first solution wasnt working tho